# Javascript: first letter of a string in array does not assigned new value. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the following code, first letter of a string in array at `index 0` does not gets replaced by the uppercase value although you can access the first letter with `arr[0][0]`. Why?

```
var arr = ["mangoes","orange","apple"];
arr[0][0] = arr[0][0].toUpperCase();
arr;
```

thanks
bt

Comment: I don't believe [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) is in place.  It **returns** what you give it in upper case.

Comment: Strings are immutable. You need to create a new string.

Comment: Strings in JavaScript are immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you cannot assign a value to arr[0][0], which is a pointer within a string. You need to replace the string arr[0] with a new value:

```
var arr = ["mangoes", "orange", "apple"];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+arr[i].substring(1);
}
console.log(arr); // ["Mangoes", "Orange", "Apple"]
```

Comment: A simpler way: `arr.forEach((el, i) => arr[i] = arr[i][0].toUpperCase() + el.slice(1));`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero Save even more bytes with a `map()` like `arr = arr.map((el) => el[0].toUpperCase() + el.slice(1));`

Answer (score -1):

arr[0] = arr[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[0].slice(1);

From here: [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Comment: Why not just mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: If you can post the answer from another question as the answer to this question then this question is a duplicate of that other question. Flag as a duplicate instead of answering.

Comment: ok, but I don't see the option to flag as duplicate.

Comment: It's not directly visible, if you click the flag icon below the question's tags then it brings up some options that I think include 'flag as duplicate.'

Comment: yeah, i did that and it shows three options "spam", "abusive" or "in need of moderator intervention" , but no duplicate